# Vue-router not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue-router

I have installed vue-router with node. 
This is my project url `http://localhost/UserApp/public`.

And the two vue routes i used is `/home` & `/about` 
So when i click on the home routes. it redirects me to `http://localhost/home` 
but it should be `http://localhost/UserApp/public/home`.
So when i reload the page. it throws `object not found` Error. As there is no route such as `http://localhost/home`.
How do i solve the problem?

**app.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  { path: '/home', component: Home },
  { path: '/about', component: About }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
   mode : 'history',
   routes // short for `routes: routes`
})
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/{name}',function(){
    return redirect('/');
})->where('name','[A-Za-z]+');
```

Myheader.vue

```
<router-link to="/home" class="navbar-item">Home</router-link>
<router-link to="/about" class="navbar-item">About</router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the base application path in the vue-router's configuration,

DOCS: https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#base

**base** should be `/UserApp/public` from what I can tell

As a routing option, try:

```
Route::get('/{any}', function(){
    return view('index');
})->where('any', '.*');
```